# Multi-Harddrive Tower, Do I have to Worry about Overheating

Tags: hard-drive, sata, overheating

I have been thinking of getting a third hard drive. Right now I have two already in my tower. The HDDs have a small compact separate 3-space bay in the bottom front of the tower.

In general, should I worry about overheating? Should I monitor the heat for awhile?

Specifics, I already have some cheap-medium 1TB drives form 3-4 years ago. And am thinking of getting a decent 3TB now.

All SATA III (the old ones could be SATA II).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This depends on the air flow in your case and on the ambient temperature. And on the drives themselves.

If you live in the tropics, no air flows over the drives and they get hot (e.g. being multi-platter old 7200+ RPM drives). Then yes, worry. Measure the temperature (software wise), add a fan if needed.

If you live someplace cool and/or have some air flow past the drives they are mostly likely fine.

Bottom line: It never hurts to monitor the heat for a while. Especially if it puts your mind at ease.

Comment: Yup.  8 HDDs in this box, the drives are a little cooler than they would be simply sitting in the open with neither a fan nor enclosure.  However, that's with a 120mm fan blowing across each pair of drives and several additional fans, also.